.NET MAUI Visual Studio : Cannot Set Build Action to "None"
We have a number of XML files that we need to include in our solution that are NOT to be compiled or have any other Build Action applied to them.  We simply want to keep them in a folder and include them in version control along with other files in the solution.
When we attempt to set the Build Action to "None" we get an error that the "Property Value is Invalid" with the following details:
An error has occurred while saving the edited properties listed below:
    Build Action
One or more values are invalid. 
Cannot add 'Configuration\Config.Default\classification.xaml' 
to the project, because the path is explicitly excluded from the project (...\.nuget\packages\microsoft.maui.controls.build.tasks\
8.0.61\buildTransitive\netstandard2.0\
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.DefaultItems.targets (12,3)).


What can we set the Build Action to, in order to STOP Visual Studio from trying to do something with these files during a build?

you can include files in the folder without adding them to the solution, so VS will ignore them

@Jason : I would like the files to be included in the TFS / DevOps source control.

Not sure about TFS, but git will not care if it is part of the project or not

This is solved by setting all the build event types to "Resource" and then removing Custom Build Command" (just leave it blank).

Maybe you miss the topic Can I accept my own question? from the SO blog.
